# Proof of smoothness of Vector Fields

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

In John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* book, I have a small problem following through his proof of smoothness of vector fields.

[image: The proof]

In the last paragraph, he claims that $Yf$ is smooth since the component functions are smooth. However, how does he know that the function
$x \mapsto \frac{\partial f }{\partial x^i}|_x
$ is also smooth? It is clear how that would hold in the context of analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I don't see any reason why $x \mapsto \frac{\partial f }{\partial x^i}|_x
$ is also smooth in the context where we define a derivation at a point as a map $f \mapsto  \frac{\partial f }{\partial x^i}|_x$ instead of $x \mapsto  \frac{\partial f }{\partial x^i}|_x$.

Comment: @newbie Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} $$
means the partial derivative in the $i$th coordinate of the function $f$, in the coordinates $(x^1, \cdots, x^n)$.
If you were to write this in the "standard" way, using a chart $(U, \varphi)$, then
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p) = \frac{\partial (f \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial x_i}(\varphi(p)), $$
where the right hand side is taken in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ being the standard coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Moreover, $f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth by definition.